# Comparing Two Large Sets of Z-Scores for Relative Analysis

Tags: standard-deviation, z-score

Apologies if I do something incorrectly, this is my first time posting to stack exchange. I am also not an experienced statistician, so please bear with me if I am mistaken in some way.

I have a dataset I am working with which has 735 records. There are certain fields within this dataset which have had their Z-Score values calculated. Ideally we would like to be able to look at the Z-Score of two different fields, and be able to confidentially say "Field X is performing relatively better than Field Y". This is easy enough to achieve when 1 record is being compared to another, as a Z-Score of 1.5 > 1 for example. When we are dealing with 735 records in two different fields, which each have a unique Z-Score, how could we achieve this? Is there a statistical formula I am unaware of, or is this even possible? Obviously the mean and sum of both sets will always be 0, and the SD will always be 1, so neither of those measures indicate anything. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In what important way do you expect the z-scores to differ if they all have mean 0 and variance 1? Can you give an example? // One example might be to compare $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ with $\mathsf{Unif}(−\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}).$ Could something like that arise in your situation? // Please elaborate. What do you mean by "better?

Answer (score 0):

*Comment continued.* Fictitious data (sampled in R) for examples:

```
set.seed(2022)
w = rnorm(1000)
z.w = (w - mean(w))/sd(w)
x = rexp(1000, 1/20)
z.x = (x - mean(x))/sd(x)
y = runif(1000)
z.y = (y - mean(y))/sd(y)
```

The three histograms have very different shapes.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
XL = c(-5,5)
 hist(z.w, prob=T, xlim=XL, br=20, col="skyblue2")
 hist(z.x, prob=T, xlim=XL, br=20, col="skyblue2")
 hist(z.y, prob=T, xlim=XL, br=10, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests show that the samples
come from different distributions: all three
P-values are nearly $0,$

```
ks.test(z.w, z.x)$p.val
[1] 7.891465e-13
ks.test(z.w, z.y)$p.val
[1] 0.009697832
ks.test(z.x, z.y)$p.val
[1] 0
```

But, I have no idea which you distribution you
consider to be "best"--if any.